Какие технологии нужно использовать, чтобы написат бэкенд на c# для приложения react native
В планах имеется разработка React Native мобильного приложения.
Приложение должно уметь:

Сохранять данные локально
Реализовывать регистрацию и вход в аккаунт
Иметь бд
Иметь сервер

С фронтендом уже определились, теперь интересен бекенд
Вопрос такой:
Можно ли на C# написать сервер для такого приложения, и что бы вы рекомендовали использовать?
Слышал, что можно и на asp.net писать. Но я пока знаю, что asp для веб приложений (не для серверов)

asp для веб приложений (не для серверов) - ошибаетесь

ASP.NET Core Web API, клиентское приложение разрабатывать отдельным проектом. Общаться с сервером через API (REST/WS/gRPC).

Tutorial
